# Concat Demuxer playlist

Tags: ffmpeg, windows, concatenation

So according to the docs located here
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate
**section: Changing playlist files on the fly**

it says you can do this:

> Now you can change the looping clip by a simple move command:

```
mv next_clip.mxf dummy.mxf
```

I cant find any examples on the web of how this works.

I will test it some more but i cant seems to get this to work, I added it on the last line in place of where i would normally put the next text file to open.  but it just kept cutting off.

I am assuming that it would cut off because that once it loads up the txt file, it cant be changed.

I have seen reference to such things as "outpoint and inpoint"  but can not find any info on that either.

can someone point me in the direction to all the commands i can put into the txt file when using the concat demuxer.  i would like to learn what all i can do.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57143892/

Comment: thanks, so @gyan it is BEFORE last video in txt file plays, or is it once txt file is loaded there is no going back?    I was gonna go with the old method of  'files  video.mp4' and then the next list on the last line. file 'next.txt' ... if i stuck with that model can that last line "next.txt" be changed to say "two.txt" once the first txt file is loaded into ffmpeg?